# ChainLink oracles - are they free to use? Is there an oracle alternative onchain?

Tags: oracles, chainlink

How does it work, exactly? We just call this on-chain to get the latest price... but would our contract have to transfer some LINK to it, or what?

https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price

Which oracles are available, and what are their prices to call on-chain?
All I am trying to do is find out onchain the "current" ETH-USD exchange rate, like a median across many exchanges or whatever. It doesn't have to be super exact, just not way off. What should I use for this?

Answer (score 3):

****No**, they are not free.** Each oracle service comes with a price. You can learn more about the services they offer and their prices from the following [link](https://market.link/).

For your specific search, you can go to this [link](https://market.link/nodes/eaa65e96-c498-4af6-a682-47ff9951f75f/jobs).

If you like to learn more and prefer video, I suggest the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtHp7me2Yks&t=309s).

Comment: But in this case how come I can visit https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419#readContract and see the latest price there for free in the Read Contract tab, under latestAnswer and latestRoundData etc?

Comment: What price? Once you send the smart contract to the Ethereum network, you will be able to see it. I think you are confusing the oracle service with the Ethereum network.

Answer (score 3):

Use of Chainlink oracles can be separated into 2 categories:

### [1. Chainlink Price Feeds](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price)

The answer to where or not they are free can be found in [this stack exchange ETH question and answer.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87473/is-chainlinks-price-reference-data-free-to-consume)

TL;DR, at the moment they are free because the project is still starting, but it isn't economical for this to stay as-is forever.

### [2. Request and Recieve](https://docs.chain.link/docs/architecture-request-model)

This includes [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf) and [Chainlink API calls](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data). In order to use these, you need to send the specific oracle the LINK price of fetching the data.