# Chainlink `latestRoundData()` security / fresh data check usage

Tags: chainlink

Where can I find docs on using `latestRoundData()` recommended validation?

The below comment is in the deployed code in each `EACAggregatorProxy`.

```
Consumers are encouraged to check that they're receiving fresh data by inspecting the updatedAt and answeredInRound return values.
```

What should we be checking?

Answer (score 2):

Checking for stale prices on a Chainlink feed is a great way to keep your dapp secure and future-proof. Sometimes, tokens change addresses, apps don't want to pay node operators anymore, etc, and it makes sense to have some fallbacks [when such events occur.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133242/how-future-resilient-is-a-chainlink-price-feed/133843#133843)

The exact check you'd want to do depends on what you want your app to do.

The [Chainlink Docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/price-feeds-api-reference/) describe the two values as such:

```
updatedAt: Timestamp of when the round was updated
answeredInRound: The round ID in which the answer was computed
```

If your app is concerned about stale data (maybe more than 3 hours?), a check (in solidity) might look as such:

```js
uint256 threeHoursSec = 10800;
if(updatedAt < block.timestamp - threeHoursSec) {
  s_isPaused = true;
}
```

Where `s_isPaused` is some `bool` that controls certain functionality on your contract.

Checking `answeredInRound` is legacy from the fluxMonitor edition of Chainlink price feeds (which price feeds don't run off anymore) and it can be ignored.